# Find common elements in two arrays

Tags: c++, c, arrays

This algorithms here is to find the common elements in two arrays. Everything seems okay until I enter

```
a[]={4,3,4,2}
b[]={4,1}
```

The output should be

```
key[]={4}
```

Instead, it gives:

```
key[]={4,4}
```

How can I fix it?

```
int seqSearch(int arr[], int size, int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (arr[i] == key)
            return i;
    return 0;
}
void findDup(int a[], int b[], int& size1, int& size2, int key[], int& sizekey)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++)
            if (a[i] == b[j])
                if (seqSearch(key, sizekey, a[i]) == 0)
                {
                    key[sizekey] = a[i];
                    sizekey++;
                }   
}
int main() {
    int a[max], b[max], key[100], size1, size2, sizekey=0;
    findDup(a, b, size1, size2, key, sizekey);
}
```

Comment: Simple answer is to not add 4 when it is found the second time.

Comment: Even simpler solution is to use the standard algorithm `std::set_intersection()`.    Bear in mind that `set_intersection()` assumes both input ranges are sorted, and - depending on your needs - there may be a need to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Peter, ... or just put values into `std::set`.

Comment: @Peter, thank you for your solutions. But this is an exercise so almost all algorithms have to be coded by hand

Comment: @Phineas -- Maybe the goal is also for you to use the appropriate data structure.  A hash set or hash table is one way to do this (where a hash set would be `std::unordered_set`).  And as to your solution, imagine if there were 100 numbers in each array.  You would be looping 10000 times.  That solution is a poor one.

Comment: If a is {4,4} and b is also {4,4}, what should the output be?

Comment: Please change the tag from C++ to C. There is no c++ code at all. And in C++ it would be a one-liner using std::set_intersection

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Common of a and b: {4}

Answer (score 0):

Index `0` is a valid index which function `seqSearch` may return.

Use `-1` instead (also in `if (seqSearch(key, sizekey, a[i]) == 0)`).

Comment: It worked. thank you. But why is return 0 differs from return -1? Isn't it just a value like true/false? There are cases return both 0 and i?

Comment: @Phineas: Index `0` is a valid index which function `seqSearch` may return. I stated that at the top of the answer. What part of this statement are you finding difficult to understand???

Comment: I know that you have stated above, but I don't understand that why -1 is differents from 0. Why Index 0 is a valid index which function seqSearch may return but not Index `-1` is a valid index which function `seqSearch` may return. Is 0 a special number? I am a absolute beginner so there are a lot of simple question that I don't know

Comment: @Phineas: In `a[]={4,3,4,2}`, what is the index of the first `4`?

Comment: array in C++ always start with 0, sooooo `0`.

Comment: @Phineas: Good. Did that answer your question?

Comment: well that's simple :l . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using key as 'int array' use the std::unordered_set. So, you don't need of separate count variable as well and it will not accept the duplicate there.

Answer (score 0):

In seqSerach return value as bool which means if value already exists in array or not. Use that in your second function accordingly. Issue is that 0 is valid integer which you are returning.